# git push changes files group to nobody (501)

Tags: git

I have a git setup to deploy my website to my server (based on [this guide](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto)). However, I'm faced with the following issue:

Everything I `git push` the group owner of most of my website files and folders are changed to `nobody` (501).

Here's an example:

```
drwxrwxr-x 11 git www-data   4096 Nov 21 17:28 app
-rw-r--r--  1 git      501   1646 Nov 21 17:28 artisan
```

If I do `chown -R git:www-data` before I do a `git push`, the group owner is `www-data`. But every time I `git push`, the group owner is changed to `501`.

I have set `sharedRepository`:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
git config core.filemode false
```

The user `git` was part of a group that's now deleted, but `git` is part of `www-data` in `/etc/group`:

```
www-data:x:502:git,nginx
```

How can I fix my git setup in order for git to retain the `www-data` group for all my files and folders?

Comment: "The user git was part of a group that's now deleted" but you're seeing files in a numerical group 501, rather than a name, which I bet was git's group. You should fix git's default group to be something that exists.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The `usermod -g` command fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the process running your `post-receive` hook is being run by whatever user you're using for your remote (ie. user@hostname). It will create files according to its default group, just like normal.

To fix this, you'd have to change the default group of that user on the remote machine. Or use a different user.

In general, using Git as a deployment tool is a bad idea. It seriously resists the idea and is very limited. Any small convenience you gain now will be lost in having to increasingly fight it. You're better off using a real deployment tool.

Comment: Could you suggest some deployment tools that I can look into?

Comment: @Lee Sorry, I can't. I'm not up on deployment tools. I've just watched a lot of people try to force Git into being one.